# Is there a way to use a generic argument's own generic argument in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have this interface, with two generic parameters, and a `Descriptor<T>` class:

```java
public interface DescriptorFinder<D extends Descriptor<T>, T> {
    D find(Class<? extends T> describedClass);
}

public abstract class Descriptor<T> {
    private final Class<? extends T> describedClass;

    public Descriptor(Class<? extends T> describedClass) {
        this.describedClass = describedClass;
    }

    public Class<? extends T> getDescribedClass() {
        return describedClass;
    }
}
```

Using those foundations I can create an `NumberDescriptor` to describe a number:

```java
public class NumberDescriptor extends Descriptor<Number> {
    private boolean handlesDecimalPart;

    public NumberDescriptor(Class<? extends Number> describedClass) {
        super(describedClass);
    }

    public boolean handlesDecimalPart() {
        return handlesDecimalPart;
    }

    public void setHandlesDecimalPart(boolean handlesDecimalPart) {
        this.handlesDecimalPart = handlesDecimalPart;
    }
}
```

And then have a `DescriptorFinder` for it:

```java
public class NumberDescriptorFinder implements DescriptorFinder<NumberDescriptor, Number> {
    @Override
    public NumberDescriptor find(Class<? extends Number> describedClass) {
        NumberDescriptor descriptor = new NumberDescriptor(describedClass);
        
        if (describedClass == Double.class || describedClass == Float.class) {
            descriptor.setHandlesDecimalPart(true);
        }
        
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Well, that `DescriptorFinder<NumberDescriptor, Number>` is pretty weird to use,  I would like to remove the second generic parameter and reduce it to `DescriptorFinder<NumberDescriptor>`. So I tried something like this:

```java
public interface DescriptorFinder<D extends Descriptor<?>> {
    D find(Class<? extends T> describedClass); // How to get T?
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to get `D`'s `T` argument, for example, if I had `D` as `Descriptor<Number>`, I want to get `Number` so I can have `Class<? extends Number>`.

Comment: Do you even need `T`? Wouldn't `D find(Class<?> describedClass);` be enough?

Comment: Well since this interface may create a subclass of `Descriptor<T>` from the given class, doing `new IntegerDescriptor(someUnknownClass)` for example won't compile, so I'll have to do runtime checks, which is possible though.

Comment: As it's currently written, it's impossible to subclass _`Descriptor`_. Code up _`IntegerDescriptor`_ to extend it. You'll see what I mean. You've piqued my curiosity. It's an interesting puzzle. But I'm struggling to understand what this means:  „*...But I couldn't get the `T` argument from `Descriptor<T>` of the `D` parameter...*“. So it'd be cool if you edited your _Q_ with pseudocode  that shows how you envisage _`DescriptorFinder`_ being instantiated? And _`find()`_ being called? Ditto for _`Descriptor`_? Please? TIA.

Comment: @deduper I put a concrete example now, but this time with a `NumberDescriptor`. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thx jeuxjeux20. Yeah no. What you've done is what you need. That _`T`_ of _`DescriptorFinder`_ is for type safety. With the _`Class<?>`_ approach that you've already tried, you could pass a _`Class<String>`_ or a _`new RandoArray[0].getClass()`_  or anything into _`NumberFinder.find()`_ with impunity. And that's how type safety goes out the window. Which would defeat the purpose of using generics; whose raison d'être is type safety. So your _`T`_ is like the _`T`_ in [_the JDK's Function interface_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html).

Comment: @deduper Alright then, anyway I'll just create subinterfaces to "hide" that clutter, like `interface NumberDescriptorFinder extends DescriptorFinder<NumberDescriptor, Number> {}`, thanks!